# Is there a way to install a VSIX extension in Visual Studio Preview?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions

I'm trying to use the recently-released [.NET 7 RC1](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-dotnet-7-rc-1) with Visual Studio 17.4 Preview 2.  Unfortunately, I'm unable to build my project because it uses ANTLR at one point, and the ANTLR extension for Visual Studio didn't get installed.

I have the VSIX file, but when I run it, it says:
[image]

When I open the Manage Extensions window, there doesn't appear to be any option anywhere to load an extension from disc.

What is the mechanism for getting this extension installed into a Preview version of VS?

Comment: The vsix package brings a version range with it and only those VS Version allow to install it. The Preview has its own version number (normally a minor version+1 compared to the current VS) and is presumably not in the valid range of the package. Get the author to officially support previews or build the sources yourself and pray that it works.

Comment: Looking at the https://github.com/kaby76/AntlrVSIX/blob/master/VsIde/source.extension.vsixmanifest source it only supports up to VS2019 and no version VS2022. Independent of preview or something else.

Comment: https://github.com/kaby76/AntlrVSIX#readme

Comment: @ralf That's a good point.  Suddenly I have no idea how I ever got it working on my non-Preview VS2022 install! [insert "this just raises further questions" meme here]